# I want to run mouse and keyboard simultaneously at laptop and PC

Tags: laptop, keyboard, desktop-computer

I want to run mouse and keyboard simultaneously at laptop and PC. I don't want to switch from 1 device to another like synergy software offers, but instead, when I'm working on my laptop, the keyboard and mouse should be active on PC as well and duplicate the actions.

Any ideas? Maybe there's some sort of mouse/keyword that connects to both PC and Laptop at the same time?

Comment: I suspect you may have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the point of this setup?

Comment: Keep in mind that the screen layout in laptop and PC won't be necessarily the same, so clicking the mouse at one position may issue a command on the laptop but not on the PC, etc... Also, please add an OS tag. E.g. under Linux, you can simulate and forward USB devices.

Comment: -1 because questions in comments are still unanswered and the question looks incomplete without them.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of Synergy is supposed to allow you to use any mouse/keyboard that is attached to any computer in the cluster. You could use the track pad on the laptop or the mouse/keyboard attached to the PC.

If you are truly looking for mirroring, as in each computer mimics the mouse movements that the other is making, then Synergy is not what you are looking for. I do not know if any program that does this as the computers would need everything laid out and configured exactly the same to make this viable. Which kind of defeats the point of using multiple computers.